# How to create read only list view in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-server, permissions, list-view

Is it possible to create read only view for list?

The people having edit access also should not be able to edit any record in this view.

Please advise.

Comment: Why not configure unique permissions on the list such that those edit users only have read access?

Comment: Dear nsturdivant, i am searching for OOB feature to do it. is it possible to do this by using OOB feature of SharePoint list? Also we can't change permission of edit users to read access.Edit users should have edit access to list but only read permission for one particular view.

Comment: I don't see the point of a read-only view even if it were possible to create one. Users viewing the read-only view could simply change views and edit freely since, as you mentioned, these users have edit permissions on the list anyway. You wouldn't be "securing" anything. What is the actual requirement here?

Answer (score 1):

There's few ways to achieve this. You can create a view and just show "Title" and choose default style, those items won't be clickable or editable. However, if users hover over the Ribbon, they can still find a way to edit the selected item. Also, you can delete allitems view from the drop-down, however, the URL for the allitems view will still be accessible (but just you know about the secret link.)

I would prefer to use OOTB CSWP or CQWP to roll up items without clickable links, so users can only see the items but cannot edit them.

Answer (score 1):

Create a View, Add all the columns you want to display. Hide the "Edit" column and make sure Title (Display item) column is selected instead of Title with edit column. Also make sure you uncheck "Allow individual item checkbox" under Tabular view option.
This is let user view an item when they click on Title but they will not be able to edit.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create one custom permission group and set the permission. The following permission is Default SharePoint Read Only permission group. You will get an idea how to play the permission.

[image]

In your list permission, assign the user to your customize permission instead of contribute or read only etc..

**Another method is** : Only the item creator can edit his/her items, he/she has only read access to the other items created by other users.

This feature is in the Advance List Setting under your List Setting.

[image]

Comment: my question is:the user will have edit access on list level but on one view he should have only read access. Is is possible? If possible then how?

Comment: It is not possible, there is no option to restrict the permission in view.

Answer (score -1):

you can put a list webpart on a page with this view and make the page read-only, then delete the view